# 'Yet' in present simple

Tags: present-perfect

Where can use an **yet** in the present perfect?

```
This vendor has not yet posted their profile online.
```

or

```
 This vendor has not posted their profile online yet.
```

In my mind I can use the **yet** in the end of sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Both look fine to me!

-native Nick

P.S. Since the sound of "y" in "yet" is more of a consonant than vowel sound here, you'd say,

"Where can I use **a** *yet*?"

Compare this to "a year," which is more correct than "an year." Just FYI! ^_^